# PHP SSH2 Exec - Getting PID

Tags: php, pid, ssh2-exec

How I can get PID for a process executed via SSH2.

What I have tried :

```
ssh2_exec($SSH2, 'echo `ps aux | grep -F "' . $StartCommand . '" | 
 grep -v -F "grep" | awk \'{ print $2 }\'`');
```

and

```
ssh2_exec($SSH2, $StartCommand.' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!');
```

But as a result I get in echo Resource id #2 or Resource id #3 or Resource id #4

Comment: which PID? ssh2_exec  Execute a command on a remote server ... did you want to know it on your server or on remote? And why did you want to know the PID?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [ssh2_fetch_stream](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-fetch-stream.php) function to fetch this ressource.

```
$stdout_stream = ssh2_exec($SSH2, $command);
$err_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stdout_stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
$dio_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stdout_stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);

stream_set_blocking($err_stream, true);
stream_set_blocking($dio_stream, true);

$result_err = stream_get_contents($err_stream);
$result_dio = stream_get_contents($dio_stream);
```